# Simple (variable) PWM generator for led driver that accepts PWM input

Tags: pwm, 555, led-driver

I have a cc(constt. current) led driver that accepts pwm input in the range of 2v-8v for led dimming.Can I provide this pwm signal from a 555 based pwm generator? If so how can I keep o/p pwm(from 555) in the range 2v-8v(driver spec.)

Edit:Here's the ckt I'm using powered by 5v(7805 regulator),I'll be using pwm output directly from pin 3 through 56ohm resistor(won't be using mosfet etc.)
How can I calculate frequency and amplitude of the pwm from this ckt?
[image]

Comment: Yes, just make sure that the frequency is within the recommended limits for the LED driver.  The 2-8V range is the HIGH voltage for the PWM input, low should be 0; just power your 555 circuit with 2-8V (probably easiest to just use 5) and make sure that the grounds are connected.

Comment: So I guess I can use a 7805 regulator to power 555 ckt.The resultant pwm signal will be in the range mentioned.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Yes, 7805 will do. If you need help on that, then construct your circuitry and post here with your questions.

Comment: Yes,I'll update the ckt I'm going to use.

Comment: Vir you should post that as an answer.